# What blocks do games in the Trackmania series contain?

Tags: trackmania-series

I would like to have an exhaustive list of all blocks for for all games of the Trackmania series? I built a track on Trackmania Nations Forever, and I would like to know whether it is possible to build a similar track for the other games of the Trackmania series.

I am asking for the games of the Trackmania series that have been published so far (see list below):

[image]

Comment: I modified the question to make it on-topic: please let me know if the question is okay as it stands now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Trackmania Nations Forever](http://forum.maniaplanet.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=29766):

[image]

[TrackMania 2 Stadium blocks](http://forum.maniaplanet.com/viewtopic.php?f=266&t=20664#p173772):

[image]

[Trackmania 2 Valley blocks](http://forum.maniaplanet.com/viewtopic.php?f=266&t=21114):

[image]